# Como dar a estilos dentro del Iframe

Tags: html, css

```
<frameset rows="100%,*">
    <frame id="inlineFrameExample"  src="paginaweb"><noframes>
            <body> 
            </body>
        </noframes>
</frameset>
```

estoy trayendo una web en este iframe, intente darle estilos con Css, pero no los toma.

```
.div-dentro-del-iframe{
   display:none;
}
```

Mi pregunta es cómo podría acceder a un div dentro para otorgarle propiedades css.

Gracias.

Comment: 1) Los frames son distintos a los iframes.- 2) Los frames están obsoletos.- 3) Pones el CSS dentro de la página del iframe

Comment: estoy colocando el css donde tengo el frame. la idea es ocultar un div que esta trayendo el frame.

Comment: No digo dentro del frame, digo que lo coloques en la página que muestras en el frame

Comment: es que para mostrarla en otra página, sin alterar nada de la original.

Comment: Para eso debe brindar  un [MRE]

Comment: ya encontre que no es posible por el bloqueo del cross origin, asi que supongo que no se puede.